# what happen If upgrade .NET 4.0 to 4.6

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I've made a project 2 years a go , It used `.NET 4.0` and know I Want to Upgrade `.NET FrameWork to 4.6` , I haven't any experience about this and I want to know does it take too long ? what problems will be happen ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is 'very little'.  In general, the later versions add to the existing .Net structure and change as little as possible. Therefore you should be able to change the target framework and click rebuild and you are good to go.

There are a few caveats:

1. You must remember to ensure that the installation has access to the .Net framework version that you wish to use.  For some computers that may mean setting it as a pre-requisite and / or including the version in your installers.
2. Although rare, there may be some things that may change in a breaking manner.  If that is the case you will normally be guided by the compiler on any changes that are needed when you rebuild.
3. There may well be better ways of doing things since you wrote the original code.  You need to decide before you start whether you are going to look to upgrade your code at the same time.

Finally, if you change the target version and it looks like being too much work when you rebuild then you can always change it back again...